# HTML not supporting arabic language

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am working on a project which i need to convert it in Arabic. i am using `codeigniter`. when I write the Arabic in html it show me that (?????) for Arabic.

This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
</head>
<body>
<h1 dir='rtl'
lang='ar'>checking</h1>
<p dir="rtl" lang="ar" style="color:#e0e0e0;font-size:20px;">رَبٍّ زِدْنٍي عِلمًا</p>
</body>
</html>
```

it shows me text like that:
[image]

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: it does support it: https://jsfiddle.net/ncwpnhkk/ , why are you using HTML 4 anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see you are using some html5 based attributes like `dir` so you need to convert the `html4` document to **`html5`** doctype and use lang attribute on html tag and meta tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ar">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
```

---

A sample demo is below:

```html
<h1 dir='rtl' lang='ar'>checking</h1>
<p dir="rtl" lang="ar" style="color:#e0e0e0;font-size:20px;">رَبٍّ زِدْنٍي عِلمًا</p>
```

the view source of this snippet looks something like this:

[image]

---

Comment: i have dont that to but the result is same in the codeigniter i have 2 files login and forget password arabic language is working for login but when i use same code for forget pass then its not working

Comment: @sheraziqbal i have added a demo of SO snippet you can see that is working quite perfect. I guess there could be other structural issue then.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding meta charset for arabic at the begning

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"  CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=iso-8859-6">
```

or
Displaying Arabic text using PHP

1. Don't use the short tags . Use the full tags
2. Remove the quotes and semicolon from the first line and others that are outside the php tags

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">";
   ```
3. Close the span tag `<span lang='ar-kw'`
4. Make sure save the file with utf-8 encoding. You might be saving it with another coding.

Comment: better to use utf-8 than iso for arabic so it'd be like this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`, also this is old for xhtml, html before, the new one with HTML 5 is just `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below as your startup file, it is HTML5, also with this `<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">` you won't need to repeat it in every single element. use this and you're fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- your HTML structure -->
</body>
</html>
```

Concerning your issue: [**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/ncwpnhkk/1/) and [**JS Fiddle 2** -*no need for `lang` attribute*](https://jsfiddle.net/ncwpnhkk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In charset value, instead of using `utf-8`, use `windows-1256`

Answer (score 0):

Add in you php connection code just:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

And in you dislay php data code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score -2):

be sure if your file encoding is `utf-8` to make this open your file in notebad then save as then you can see this below to select `utf-8`:

[image]

if you use eclipse you can update the files default encoding through `windows-> preferences` then from left side you can expand `general` and select `content types`, and by selecting the file type you can assign its default encoding then click update like the image below, also you can find the way for each editor to update default encoding:

[image]

Comment: i am using codeigniter one html file supporting arabic language but any other is not supporting

Comment: your html files default encoding is not utf-8 , you can change by the way above in the answer and try

Comment: i have done that but one file is supporting which is login but when i use the same code for other file just to edit the textbox then its not working